# Как перемещать камеру, если курсор находится у края Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Всем добра. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы можно было перемещать камеру, например влево. Перемещается же она в том условии, если курсор находится у левого края. Само собой нужно будет двигать и в другие стороны(право, верх, низ), но левой стороны как примера достаточно. Из кода только определение позиции мыши

```
private PlayerInput _playerInput;

    private void Awake()
    {
        _playerInput = new PlayerInput();
        _playerInput.Enable();
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        Vector2 moveMousePos = _playerInput.Player.MoveCameraPos.ReadValue<Vector2>();
    }
```

Comment: @aepot Для чего это делать, если работа выполняется с курсором?

Comment: `moveMousePos` у тебя есть... так в чем проблема? это не вопрос, это хотелка с которой ты дверью ошибся, тут не письма деду морозу.

Comment: @Yaroslav `moveMousePos` то есть, а применить его куда?

Comment: Сравнить с координатами края экрана, видимо и двигать камеру, если мышь в зоне крайней области `if (moveMousePos.x < 5) { ...двинуть камеру влево... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GameObject -> UI -> Image. Автоматически появится Canvas и изображение. Растянуть изображение левому краю Canvas.
В Rect Transform в инспекторе можно указать, чтобы оно растягивалось и прилипло к левому краю экрана. При изменении разрешения экрана оно будет автоматически перемещаться к краю экрана. Но это чисто для удобства.
В камеру повесить скрипт с кодом:

```
public float VelocityMove; // Скорость движения - указать в инспекторе
public Transform Left; //Изображение слева - указать в инспекторе

void Update()
if (Input.mousePosition.x < Left.position.x)
{
    transform.position += new Vector3(-VelocityMove, 0, 0);
}
```

Остальные стороны сам догадаешься.